# Maximum number of threads in Julia

Tags: multithreading, julia

Is there a limit for the Threads in Julia? 
I followed the [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.2/manual/parallel-computing/#Setup-1) and changed the number of threads to 4 but I can't change it to 8.

EDIT: I have 8 Sys.CPU_THREADS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of threads will be capped to `Sys.CPU_THREADS`.

Comment: Thanks! But I got 8.

Comment: Did you set the environment variable `JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4`?
If you are using Atom, it might be that the option `Number of Threads` is set to something different than `global`.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be accurate anymore?
For example
`julia --threads=16 -e '@show Sys.CPU_THREADS Threads.nthreads()'` shows
`Sys.CPU_THREADS = 8`
and `Threads.nthreads() = 16` (julia 1.6.1)